# Getting data into a Model Driven Form

Tags: angular

I have a model driven form. On Init I get data from a restservice and put it into my formData Object. I would like to fill my form with this data. Is the only possible solution to this to make something like this?:

```
...
formData = {}
reproOrderForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
     name: this.formData.name,
   });
}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of

```
this.form.setValue({name: 'somevalue'})
this.form.patchValue({name: 'somevalue'})
this.form.get('name').setValueAndValidity('someValue')
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html

Comment: So lets assume I get an object with about 40 properties. I have to set them manually? There is no way to load it automatically into the matching forms?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? If the data matches the structure of the form you can just use the first code line of my answer to set all control values at once.

Comment: Ahh didn´t see that one. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd one is more forgiving when the structure is not exactly matching.